# How to unstack a list as an input of multivariable function?

Tags: python, list, function, tuples

I have a function `abc` that takes 2 numbers `x` and `y`, and then returns their sum. Could you please elaborate on how to unstack a list `[x, y]` to feed it into the function.

I would like to find an operation `f` such that `abc(f([x, y]))` equals to `abc(x, y)`. In this way, if I already have an input `z=[6, 5]`, I can do `abc(f(z))` instead of `abc(z[0], z[1])`.

```
def abc(x, y):
    return(x+y)

z= [6, 5]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can "unpack" `z` when calling the function

```
>>> abc(*z)
11
```